# How do I get my menu bar back in Sublime Text 3 Linux?

Tags: sublime-text-3

The newest version of ST3 allows linux users to remove their menu bar, but I fail to see how to bring it back. In Windows, pressing Alt shows the menu, but not so in Linux. How can I get it back? Is there a shortcut I can set, or make it so that Alt shows it?

Comment: Wow, yeah I just realised the menu is gone now that I want to change projects - this is so very unusable. None of the suggestions below worked for me on Ubuntu 16 LTS with ST3 updates all applied.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

See [Show Menu in Sublime](https://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=14809&p=56308&hilit=linux%20show%20menu#p56308):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> then type vmen

I have yet to figure out how to make it a key binding. Will update when/if I do.

Edit: see jeremija's answer below to see how to set a hotkey.

Comment: Oy - 2 and 1/2 years later and still no context menu or something to bring it back.

Comment: @Blossoming_Flower - thx - do you also know how to make the menu permanently appear, rather than only being visible when you hover over it with a mouse?

Comment: Link is also dead.

Answer (score 49):

If you wish to add a hotkey you can edit your `Default (Linux).sublime-keymap` file:

- press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>
- typing `key bindings user`
- select `Preferences: Key Bindings - User`

This should open the `Default (Linux).sublime-keymap` file. Add this line:

```
{"keys": ["ctrl+alt+m"], "command": "toggle_menu"}
```

If your `.sublime-keymap` file was empty, you should wrap the above in JSON array brackets `[` and `]`, like so:

```
[
    {"keys": ["ctrl+alt+m"], "command": "toggle_menu"}
]
```

After you save the file, Sublime should reload the hotkey bindings automatically and you should be able to use the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> hotkey to toggle the menu bar.

I still miss the ability to show the menu just by pressing <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>LETTER</kbd> to open the specific menu automatically, but this (along with the Command Palette) helps a lot.

Comment: Interestingly, compared to the OP, I had the reverse problem: As of build 3065, it seems they removed the View -> *Hide* Menu entry. Your solution was the only one that actually made the menu disappear. Thank you so much!

Comment: I'm glad I could help :) The accepted answer also works for me on build 3065.

Comment: Ok, this is really strange. Maybe it has something to do with the fact I'm using a tiling window manager (namely, i3).

Comment: It's called `View: Toggle Menu`, not `View -> Hide Menu` - maybe that's why you can't find it? P.S. I've never tried i3, but I really like i3lock :)

Comment: No, it's really not there. :(

Comment: @balu, I just tried that in `i3` and I can see that option in the `Command Palette` so maybe a sublime package you have installed breaks it somehow.

Comment: No, it's been absent since right after installation when I didn't have any packages installed yet.

Answer (score 16):

You can simply press "alt+v" ,you will see menu bar then click "show menubar".

Comment: Not on Linux: if the menu bar is hidden, Alt+something does nothing.

Answer (score 6):

Close Sublime.

Edit ~/.config/sublime-text-3/Local/Session.sublime_session

Change all instances of **menu_visible** to be *true*, e.g.:
"menu_visible": true

Close, save, and restart Sublime.

Answer (score 3):

(OpenSuse 13.2)

In the file /home/.config/sublime-text-3/Local/Session.sublime_session

locate this line (around 165) and change the "false" to "true" like this:

"menu_visible": true,

Comment: This duplicates another answer and adds no new content. Please don't post an answer unless you actually have something new to contribute.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. In terminal:

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/sublime_text.desktop
```

Add `env UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0` in `Exec=` before `/opt/*` as shown in fig.

Enjoy!

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38388249/6815550